# SSIS Inserts 0 as a value in an identity column

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

we have this problem : in sqlserver 2005/2008 we create some new tables with an integer identity column as the primary key : [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL.
When loading data in this table via an SSIS dataflow task, SSIS should automatically fill the Id column. It does, BUT it starts at 0 in stead of 1. After that, when we delete all rows and do a checkident(reseed,0), we reload and it starts from 1 as it should. Any idea how we could get it right from the first time ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the tables with the identity columns directly in SSMS?  I've seen identity seeds start at 0 when using ERD tools to create the T-SQL DDL.  Also, does it matter that the ID column starts at 1?

Comment: Interesting question. I actually do not create any tables, I just "receive" the database "as is" and load it with our data. But as you asked this question I did a little test and created a table myself in SSMS. The when I load it with SSIS, all goes well and Id starts at 1. Interesting! So I'll ask how tables were created and let you know as soon as I find out.
To answer your second question, it does matter since NHibernate has a problem with an Id of 0.

Comment: Can you script out the create statement for the table to check the DDL?

Comment: The tables are not created in SSMS directly but via a visual studio database project. I've created a table this way but now again ssis starts loading from 1, so no problem here.

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TestId]    Script Date: 03/18/2010 14:26:56 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestId]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestId]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TestId]    Script Date: 03/18/2010 14:26:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestId]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestId](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Text] [nchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

Comment: This is an example of a generated script I got for one of our "problem" tables (nothing special to my humble opinion) :

-- Columns

CREATE TABLE [FINOPV].[UitsplitsingWijze]

(

[Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),

[Omschrijving] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,

...

) ON [PRIMARY]

 

GO

 

-- Constraints and indexes

ALTER TABLE [FINOPV].[UitsplitsingWijze] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_UitsplitsingWijze] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Id]) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: The DDL looks fine.  Have you checked the Identity value prior to executing the package?  Eg, dbcc checkident ('[FINOPV].[UitsplitsingWijze]').  It should be NULL if the table has not had any data inserted previously.  Also, the following should ensure what the initial seed value is.  SELECT IDENT_SEED('[FINOPV].[UitsplitsingWijze]')

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have the option [FastLoadKeepIdentity (oledb) or BulkInsertKeepIdentity (sql server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135971.aspx#sqlserver) of the destination turned on?

If so, and you are mapping a source column to your destination id column, you could get the behavior you are describing.